# How do I properly deal with race conditions in python threading while not negatively impacting performance times

Tags: python, multithreading, race-condition

I'd like to know how I can properly implement threading into my application and hold at bay any race conditions while not negatively impacting the scripts performance times.

I have omitted and simplified the code for easy reading, but would be similar in structure to what is seen below

run.py

```
from lib.DropSender import DropSender

drop_sender = DropSender( options )
drop_sender.start()
```

DropSender.py

```
from lib.Connect import Connection
import threading
import json

class DropSender:

    def __init__( self , options = {} ):
        self.system_online = True

    # This is a Web Socket connection delivering messages
    def on_message(self, message):
        js = json.loads( message )
        symbol = js[6]
        connections = Connection( self, symbol )        
        connections.start()
```

Connect.py

```
import threading
import requests
import mysql.connector
from threading import Thread, Lock

class Connection( threading.Thread ):

    def __init__( self , drop_sender, symbol ):
        threading.Thread.__init__( self )
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.lock = Lock()

    def run( self ):
        self.users_list = self.getUsers( self.symbol )
        if self.users_list["count"] > 0:
            for u in self.users_list["data"]:
                self.user_id = u["user_id"] # Example 1122
                self.amount  = u["amount"] # 923.40
                t = Thread(target=self.makePurchase, args=(self.symbol, self.user_id, self.amount, ))
                t.start()               
                # t.join()
```

I know that join() removes race conditions, but that again removes the performance speed of the script, with the threads waiting on each other

```
    def getUsers():
        # MYSQL Call to get list of users who like this 'symbol'
       my_users_arr = { "data" : data, "count" : count }
       return my_users_arr

    
    def makePurchase( self, symbol, user_id, amount ):
        # Lock it up
        self.lock.acquire()
         
        -All sorts of race conditions happening here, even with the locks acquired-
        # User ID = 1122
        # Amount 884.00 (1122's User ID mixing up with another users amount, race condition)
        # Release Lock
        self.lock.release()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the race condition you bring up occurs, and you're not specific about what it is you are trying to do...but since you are running your `makePurchase` function in a thread, I'd also gather your user via SQL there. It doesn't look like you are doing that and perhaps the way you are attempting to gather it is causing your issue.

Comment: The makePurchase function is in the thread so they happen simultaneously or as closely together as possible. The whole point of the script.

Comment: "I know that `join()` removes race conditions". Well, only in the blunt sense that your use here prevents two threads from running at the same time. Your use of the lock also ensures that basically only one thread runs at a time, since each thread exits as soon as it releases the lock. Without more detail, the only thing to suggest is that `makePurchase` either acquire and release the lock for a smaller portion of code, or that `makePurchase` simply can't be run concurrently for multiple users.

Comment: You're going to have to show us a little bit more about `makePurchase()`  Why do you think it has a race condition.   Also why, in `Connect.run()`, are you storing data in the `Connection` object that is then immediately overwritten.  These should be local variables.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the point of threads, how are you executing your code inside of `makePurchase`? You are doing nothing inside of that function with anything, and again this is likely where your issue is occuring

Comment: And yes, you are right.  You don't want `thread.join()` inside your loop.  That would essentially say each thread runs one at a time.  You really want to be using a thread pool, which makes it incredibly easy to wait for all your threads to finish.

Comment: @FrankYellin I believe you just solved my problem "Also why, in Connect.run(), are you storing data in the Connection object that is then immediately overwritten"

Comment: It looked really suspicious.  That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: @FrankYellin If you want to draft that into an answer I'll accept it, that fixed my problem. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `connection.user_id` and `connection.amount` looks suspicious.  There is only a single connection object, and these two fields are used and then immediately overwritten by setting up the next thread.

You do not show your code for `makePurchase()`, but it should not expect these two fields of `self` to be correct.

As an aside, I highly recommend the use of a thread pool.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with ThreadPool() as pool:
    for ....:
        pool.apply_async(func, args)
```

This limits the number of threads to the number of CPUs on your machine, and makes sure that all the threads are cleaned up when done.

Comment: This completely solved the problem directly related to my question. I am now also implementing ThreadPool into the application for smoother runnings. Thank you!

Comment: `ThreadPool` has all sorts of arguments that you can add to the constructor, and all sorts of operations other than `apply_async`.  Worth reading the documentation.